# Sharepoint MS-WOPI client refuses to frame to an iframe when editing, but it does allow framing when previewing

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, content-security-policy, ms-wopi

I have a [MS-WOPI](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) client in Sharepoint that correctly accepts URL requests to open Word documents like:

https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/teams/Test-EZ-CO-LON/Test-CO-L1227/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BCDE12345-ABC1-4A5F-9097-008E876E4E66%7D&action=interactivepreview

That works fairly good either by opening the URL directly in a browser, or setting it as the source in an iframe like this:

```
<iframe _ngcontent-ryg-c10="" frameborder="0" height="750" width="100%" src="https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/teams/Test-EZ-CO-LON/Test-CO-L1227/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BCDE12345-ABC1-4A5F-9097-008E876E4E66%7D&action=interactivepreview"></iframe>
```

So, that URL works perfectly fine for both direct opening and using it in an iframe.

The problem is, that if change the [WOPI action value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_protocols/ms-wopi/429749b7-5ec3-4553-a589-0ec5240121ad) from "interactivepreview" to an edition action value like "edit", for example, like this:

https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/teams/Test-EZ-CO-LON/Test-CO-L1227/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BCDE12345-ABC1-4A5F-9097-008E876E4E66%7D&action=edit

the URL can still be opened correctly when opened directly in the Web browser, but if this new URL is used in an iframe like this:

```
<iframe _ngcontent-ryg-c10="" frameborder="0" height="750" width="100%" src="https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/teams/Test-EZ-CO-LON/Test-CO-L1227/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BCDE12345-ABC1-4A5F-9097-008E876E4E66%7D&action=edit"></iframe>
```

Then Sharepoint refuses to frame, sending this [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) error message:

Refused to frame 'https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com".

So, in summary:

- For non-editable WOPI actions (e.g. "interactivepreview") the URL works well for all scenarios (both within an iframe and non-iframe).
- For editable WOPI actions (e.g. "edit"), the URL works well only if consumed directly (non-iframe).
- For editable WOPI actions, the URL does not work when used in an iframe because the aforementioned error.

Is this a WOPI misconfiguration, a Sharepoint misconfiguration, a client (browser) request misconfiguration, or something else?

Comment: `frame-ancestors` does check all parent contexts up the DOM  Looks like `action=edit` mode uses some intermedia iframe. If CSP is under your control, add `https://myCompany.sharepoint.com` into `frame-ancestors` directive. Otherwise irame headers are ruled by MS-WOPI server, maybe it's possible to solve via [host page headers](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hostpage.html#host-page-headers).

Comment: Assuming from the error message and from the fact that your files are served from the sharepoint.com domain, you're running on SharePoint Online (=not SharePoint Server), therefore the SP instance is not under your control and you can't set the CSP as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/330765/content-security-policy-settings-for-sharepoint-si.html.

Comment: @rocky that's correct.

Comment: Then it's not going to work. There are some nasty workarounds like intercepting the request in a browser plugin or building your own hostpage and translating sourcedoc to wopisrc but I wouldn't recommend any of them. A much better option is to just display a link to the file and let the user open it in a new window. Btw - is there an option (button) to switch to "edit" from "interactivepreview"?

Comment: @rocky,  yes, it is such a button. At this point, I'm just serving the document in a new browser window.